# Link currently selected email to selected cell of the active Excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I want to link the currently selected email to the selected cell of the active Excel sheet.

Error displayed:

> Object doesn't support this property or method

pointing to:

```
rngSelection.Value = olItem.GetInspector.URL
```

Outlook code:

```vb
Sub CopyLinkToSelectedEmail()

Declare all variables
Dim olItem As Object
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim rngSelection As Excel.Range

' Get the currently selected item(email) in Outlook
Set olItem = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)

' Check the type of the selected item
Select Case TypeName(olItem)
    Case "MailItem"
        ' Get the active Excel workbook and worksheet
        Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
        Set xlWorkbook = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook
        Set xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.ActiveSheet

        ' Get the currently selected cell in the excel worksheet
        Set rngSelection = xlApp.Selection

        ' Check the type of the selected cell
        If TypeName(rngSelection) = "Range" Then
            ' Copy the link to the email to the selected worksheet cell
            rngSelection.Value = olItem.GetInspector.URL

        Else
            ' Display a message if the selected cell is not a valid range
           MsgBox "A valid cell must be selected in the Excel worksheet to run this code.", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation
        End If

    Case Else
        ' Display a message and exit the macro if the selected item is not a mail item
        MsgBox "An email mail item must be selected to run this macro.", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation
        Exit Sub

End Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In the following line of code:

```
rngSelection.Value = olItem.GetInspector.URL
```

The [Inspector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.inspector) class doesn't provide the `URL` property. If you need to uniquely identify items in Outlook you may get the Outlook item instance by using the [Inspector.CurrentItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.inspector.currentitem) property which returns an object representing the current item being displayed in the inspector.

```
Dim myItem As Object 
Set myItem = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
```

Then you can use properties and methods to identify items. From the first sight, you may consider using the `EntryID` property if you deal with a single account and only on your machine. But a better approach is to introduce your own ID which can be stored in a user property, see [PropertyAccessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.propertyaccessor) which allows getting and setting item-level properties that are not explicitly exposed in the Outlook object model